# failed to connect to Mysql at [AWS RDS ADDRESS] unable to connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

Our company has a database server on AWS which other the employees can connect to it with MySQL, but when I tried, I got this error message, how can I solve it?
I tried to reconfigure MySQL server but it didn't work. also I double checked username, password, url and port.

[image]

Comment: Is there a vpc or vpn required?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes I connected to the vpn

Comment: Are you using a RDS MySQL instance or do you have an RDS instance running on EC2. Two very different things.

Comment: @smac2020 I am using MySQL with using link tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-rds-mysql-workbench/

Comment: I will provide a bit of detail in an answer

Answer (score 1):

To connect to an RDS MySQL instance from MySQL WOrkbench on your dev machine,  check a few things.

First, get the full endpoint to the database from AWS Management console.

[image]

Ensure the database is publicly accessable.

Also, make sure that you set up your inbound rules correctly.

Once you do these things, you can use MySQL Workbench to connect.

[image]

In the hostname field, make sure you put in the hostname you copied from AWS Management console. Do not put in extra information such as:

dbc:mysql://forxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

make sure it is:

forxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

THen specify the user name and password and MySQL Workbench will connect:

[image]

Comment: all the steps are checked but they were correct and didn't help

Comment: After all thse steps are performed, I've never seen a connection not work. Are your inbound rules correct?